# How can I make a resizeable input field

Tags: front-end

Web pages typically have input areas that can be resized by the user. How can I make something like that in Mathematica?

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'd share a couple of widgets I routinely use and have been tested for a couple of years. The web like behaviour can be obtained by combining `InputField` with `Pane`.

```
noteField[Dynamic[notes_, ___], 
  OptionsPattern[ImageSize -> {160, 50}]] := 
 DynamicModule[{imagesize = OptionValue[ImageSize]},
  Framed[
   Pane[
    EventHandler[
     InputField[Dynamic[notes], String, Appearance -> None, 
      Background -> RGBColor[1, 1, 0.925], 
      BaseStyle -> {LineIndent -> 0}, FieldHint -> "Enter note here", 
      FieldSize -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Dynamic[imagesize], 
      ImageMargins -> {{0, 2}, {2, 0}}],
     "ReturnKeyDown" :> 
      FrontEndExecute[{NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "\n", 
         After]}]],
    AppearanceElements -> {"ResizeArea"},
    ImageMargins -> 0,
    ImageSize -> Dynamic[imagesize]
    ],
   FrameMargins -> 0,
   FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.6],
   ImageMargins -> 0
   ]
  ]

field = "";
noteField[Dynamic[field]]
```

[image]